# How to beautify the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am sick of this kind of URL:

```
 www.domain.com/something/?id=person&photos=photoID&variable1=others&...
```

I am using apache, learning to write .htaccess now. Can anyone show me the basic code for this one?

Ugly:

```
 www.domain.com/something/?id=person&photos=photoID
```

Goal:

```
 www.domain.com/something/person/photoID
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^something/(.*)/(.*)$ something/?id=$1&photos=$2 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an extremely helpful article on [Mod_Rewrite](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting)