# How to create a beautiful post links without ID

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a link like this:

```
 http://localhost/mywebsite/post.php?title=my-post-title&id=2
```

Or

```
 http://localhost/mywebsite/post/my-post-title/2/
```

(using mvc)

But I need to show links without ID, Like many sites on the Internet.

ex:

```
 localhost/mywebsite/post/my-post-title/
```

Comment: If you already have the second then why not just remove the ID from the end and have it use `my-post-title` as the identifier?

Comment: @MichaelRushton , ID Is identifier. For security and beauty, I want to be a secret ID.

Comment: @aldrin27 , My own php mvc.

Comment: If you want it to be secret then remove it from the link and use `my-post-title` as the identifier.

Comment: @MichaelRushton , Thank you,  `my-post-title` as the identifier not bad for performance ? Do in sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/ `guide-url-rewriting` is identifier !?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL must contain a unique identifier. Without it there is no way for your application to know which post to show. In this case you need to create a second unique identifier for your post (in addition to the integer ID): this is called a [slug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug).

So, in addition to the `id` and `title` columns add a `slug` column with a `UNIQUE` key. This column should be a URL-safe string conversion of the post title (e.g. a title of "This is my first post!" could give a slug of "this-is-my-first-post"). This may require prepending an extra character (or more) if the slug is already in use, i.e. if you have two posts with the title "This is a post" then the first will have the slug "this-is-a-post" and the second will have the slug "this-is-a-post-2".

Once the slug has been created and assigned to the post this will then be used as the identifier in the URL. Using `mod_rewrite` you'll rewrite `http://localhost/mywebsite/post/my-post-title` to `http://localhost/mywebsite/post.php?slug=my-post-title` and then query the database for the post where `slug = $_GET['slug']`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought can create a hidden ID. That this was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `mod_rewrite` to beautify your URLs. Check this link out: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Here is an example `mod_rewrite` for above:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^mywebsite/(.*)/(.*)$ mywebsite/post/?title=$2 [QSA]
```

Via - [How to beautify the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824275/how-to-beautify-the-url)

Comment: He wants the link without the ID. You've just rewritten more-or-less what he's (probably) used for the second example link.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem , Thanks you. But I want a link without ID. Exactly like: `sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/` (Without any ID) *** With `RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/(.*)$ post.php?title=$1&id=$2 [QSA]` my link from `http://localhost/mywebsite/post.php?title=MyTitle&ID=MyID` converted to `http://localhost/mywebsite/post/MyTitle/MyID` *** In fact I want to hide ID for security and beauty. :-D

Comment: @MichaelRushton Just out of curiosity, what should I add to the above rule to remove the id part. I'm still learning how `mod_rewrite` works myself and this could really help me out later :)

Comment: `^post/(.*)$ post.php?slug=$1`